# Ubuntu as Hyper-V guest : multi-monitor and auto-detect resolution

Tags: multiple-monitors, display-resolution, ubuntu-gnome, 17.04, hyper-v

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384602/ubuntu-hyper-v-guest-display-resolution) post was really helpful to figure out resolution issues.

1. How do I setup grub such that the resolution auto-resizes when the VM window is moved from one monitor to another with different resolutions.
2. How do I make use of multiple monitors ?